# Mockito : What is the difference between 'thenReturn()' and 'thenAnswer()'?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Both the way I can call the method and apply the logic,

Example

````
thenAnswer(val -> {
            //logic
            return newValue;
        });


thenReturn(callMethod1(obj));

obj callMethod1(obj){

//Logic
return obj;
}```
````

Answer (score 4):

`thenReturn()` needs an object to return, while `thenAnswer()` needs the object of the class implementing interface.
So, if you need to return a fixed value, the correct method to use is `thenReturn()`, but if you need to do some kind of operations with the object you're returning, then you should use `thenAnswer()`, which will invoke an Answer instance.
In resume, it's just a matter of implementation, and choosing one or another just depends on what purposes you have.

Comment: Thanks for your response, "but if you need to do some kind of operations with the object you're returning, then you should use thenAnswer()" I have used thenAnswer() as I am applying logic on the object I am retuning.

Comment: @VasanthakumarJagannathan in that case you're using the return correctly. Just keep in mind that a `thenReturn()` all it does is a "simple" return, while `thenAnswer()` works invoking a method of the `Answer` instance. So, in a few words, always you need to keep working (keep executing code) with the object you're returning, you'll need to use `thenAnswer()`.

Answer (score 1):

`thenReturn`, as the name says, just returns some value when the mocked condition occurs.

`thenAnswer` invokes the [`answer`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.0.0/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html#answer-org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock-) method of an `Answer` instance, and allows you to execute some arbitrary code when the condition occurs.